# MySQL Error 1054: Unknown column in 'field list' on INSERT

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL Workbench to create a database. I have a table called USERS defined as follows:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `UID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
  `USERNAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(64) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `USER_NAME_UNIQUE` (`USERNAME`),
  KEY `USERS_ROLES_REF_IDX` (`USER_ROLE`),
  CONSTRAINT `USERS_ROLES_REF` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ROLE`) REFERENCES `roles_ref` (`ROLE_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `MyDB`.`users_after_ins_trig`
AFTER INSERT ON `MyDB`.`users`
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    insert into profiles (username) VALUES (new.username);
end
$$
```

When I go to forward engineer the database and create it, the script gives me the following error. As you can see from above, the username is part of the table. What gives?

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1054: Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `MyDB`.`USERS` (`UID`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'user1', 'blahpassword')
```

Comment: We see the schema for `users`, but not for `profiles`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you are inserting into `profiles` from your trigger?  I'm guessing `profiles` does not have a username column.