# MySQL Column giving Insert / Update erros

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, civicrm

Having a strange problem with a mysql table. I can use the column 'entity_table' without any issues in a SELECT statement, but it is giving me issues with any UPDATE or INSERT statement.

Specifically, I am getting

```
"Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'entity_table' in 'field list'"
```

The column definitely exists, as I can use it in a SELECT statement as mentioned above.

I get the exact same error on both of the following statements:

```
INSERT INTO `civicrm_note` (`entity_table`) VALUES ('civicrm_relationship')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `civicrm_note` (`entity_id`) VALUES (513576)
```

which is interesting since I am not even referencing entity_table in the field list in the second statement.

No problems on any other table or field in the database as far as I can tell.

This SELECT statement works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM civinbla.civicrm_note WHERE entity_table = 'civicrm_contact';
```

Comment: Show your select statement.

Comment: Could `civicrm_note` be a view?

Comment: Maybe there's a trigger associated with the table, and the error is coming from there.

Comment: Something else is going on here. I'd have a very close look at your schema.

Comment: Added the SELECT statement. civicrm_note is not a view. There are triggers on the table - I'm going to look into that now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was related to triggers. The triggers on our DB were all programmatically created using a MySQL user that exists solely for the application. For some reason, the AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE triggers had been modified so that the DEFINER was root instead of the application user.

Changed the DEFINER to the application user, and everything worked fine.

Comment: bpmccain, You might be interested to know that a bunch of us are very close to launching a CiviCRm StackExchange site - see http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm . While we have over 300 committers who are active enough recently, we need a few more people like you who have 200 reputation on another StackExchange site to commit. Please consider helping us out with this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's a trigger problem as Barmar mentioned. Take a look here:
[MySQL Error 1054: Unknown column in 'field list' on INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692491/mysql-error-1054-unknown-column-in-field-list-on-insert)

Additionally, if `entity_id` is the primary key, you might want to insert both values (`entity_table` and `entity_id`) in one statement. Otherwise, the table will not take your insert.

I don't know though, if this would throw such an error.

Comment: entity_id is not the PK, but there is an id field with is the PK. This is auto-incremented though and doesn't need to be included. Looking to triggers

Comment: I hear you. Feel free to post your solution when you find it. Wish you success.